# Show thumbnail image of video using jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: php, jquery-file-upload

I am using jQuery-File-Upload, https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload for uploading files. My requirement is, when user upload video type file then thumbnail image of video generate. Is it possible?

Comment: How, can you please help.

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9053234

Comment: possible duplicate of [need to create thumbnail for video uploading (very simple code)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053048/need-to-create-thumbnail-for-video-uploading-very-simple-code)