# Facebook like video uploader generate thumbnails before publish

Tags: php, jquery, html, video, ffmpeg

Is there a jQuery plugin that could generate video preview thumbnails even before user uploads it? I notice that Facebook could do so but do not know any plugin that has the same functionality.

Try uploading a video on facebook, notice that even before you publish it or the progress bar is still in progress, preview images of the video are available already.

I tried searching the net and most answers pertain to installing **ffmpeg** having [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053048/need-to-create-thumbnail-for-video-uploading-very-simple-code) as a reference.

I haven't tried it yet but looking into it, it seems that the video should be uploaded first before it could generate a thumbnail. But I what I want is a preview of the thumbnail to be generate BEFORE the video is uploaded (similar to facebook).

This is so that I have the transaction to select a video and generate a preview thumbnail at the same time even before the video is published on the server. Once I hit the "publish" button, it will upload the video to the server, upload/save generated preview thumbnail, save info to database at the same time.

Comment: I would guess, facebook is using an asyncronous upload server who is capable of working with junks of uploaded data and giving response via ajax to a listening client channel

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to download a video and make its thumbnail. You can make a request via Facebook API to get it. You just have to precise that you want the attribute "picture" in the result; this attribute contains the path of the thumbnail of the video. You will find more explanation by following this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/video/

Comment: I meant when uploading videos on a website. I was just citing Facebook as an example of implementation.